# lookup google.com on 192.168.65.1:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message

Tags: linux, docker, go, alpine-linux

I have been with getting my docker image to issue srv record queries. It seems the golang guys broke the existing behavior by disregarding malformed records. I heard there was a fix, but I keep trying newer versions of ubuntu/alpine linux and nothing seems to make a difference. I cannot downgrade to golang 1.10. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? like screwing up my docker file? how ca I make this code actually work in my container? 
My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    net.DefaultResolver.PreferGo=true
    cname, srvs, err := net.LookupSRV("xmpp-server", "tcp", "google.com")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("\ncname: %s \n\n", cname)

    for _, srv := range srvs {
        fmt.Printf("%v:%v:%d:%d\n", srv.Target, srv.Port, srv.Priority, srv.Weight)
    }

    // cname: _xmpp-server._tcp.google.com.
    //
    // xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:5:0
    // alt2.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
    // alt1.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
    // alt4.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
    // alt3.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
}
```

My error:

```
panic: lookup google.com on 192.168.65.1:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /app/run_stuff.go:12 +0x322
exit status 2
```

my docker file:

```
FROM golang:1.12
RUN mkdir /app 
RUN uname -a
RUN go version
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
CMD ["go","run","run_stuff.go"]
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile working fine same output as above, what command are you trying to building/running the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a Go issue. Running `go run run_stuff.go` on my mac yields the result you're expecting

```sh
$ go run run_stuff.go 

cname: _xmpp-server._tcp.google.com. 

xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:5:0
alt2.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
alt4.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
alt1.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
alt3.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
```

The issue likely has to do with your DNS settings in Docker. Using the exact same code and Dockerfile as you posted above, I ran the command `docker build -t test . && docker run --rm -it --dns 8.8.8.8 test` which builds and runs the container. The difference being that I set the `--dns` flag (see [the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for details). The result being:

```
$ docker build -t test . && docker run --rm -it --dns 8.8.8.8  test  
Sending build context to Docker daemon  27.14kB
Step 1/7 : FROM golang:1.12.4
 ---> b860ab44e93e
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2a339a5e5fde
Step 3/7 : RUN uname -a
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dac4362453e6
Step 4/7 : RUN go version
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ae654c1c4aa6
Step 5/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db3c82038173
Step 6/7 : COPY . /app/
 ---> 9dba317a267d
Step 7/7 : CMD ["go","run","run_stuff.go"]
 ---> Running in 2ea6b38869f1
Removing intermediate container 2ea6b38869f1
 ---> 0a0f817b51bb
Successfully built 0a0f817b51bb
Successfully tagged test:latest

cname: _xmpp-server._tcp.google.com. 

xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:5:0
alt4.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
alt3.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
alt1.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
alt2.xmpp-server.l.google.com.:5269:20:0
```

The default DNS server (`192.168.65.1`, usually set in `/etc/resolv.conf`) isn't capable of resolving the query. You could update the DNS settings for your host system, or add the `--dns` flag to make your code work properly in a Docker container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To add more context to this: If you change the version of golang to 1.10 in the docker file It works without any change to the DNS server. There was a change made in golang 1.11 to not support compressed hostnames. 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/vAbjprJNPV0

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27546

My issue is that I will be deploying this in a Kubernetes cluster and need a version of linux where systemd, or whatever dns resolver go uses not arbitrarily crash

Comment: If you create the executable using Go 1.10, you can run it on any type of Linux system (provided you compile it with CGO disabled and use have the same architecture, like `amd64`). In that case you'd have a multi-stage docker build. Stage 1 builds the executable and stage 2 creates the docker image you want to run in your K8s cluster.

Comment: After trying your solution I could indeed get the results I expect, but the underlying issue is still there. I will upvote this answer because It provided additional context and tools that I had not known prior.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm using Go modules, which forces you to do all sorts of stuff to get it work; so I can't quite fallback to go1.10. I also want to compile in the container itself if possible.